# php return an empty array after foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, file-get-contents

Can I avoid the empty array that generate by `foreach` ?
here is my code

```
$file="test.txt";
$open = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $open);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $domain = preg_split('/\s+/', $line,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($domain);
    echo "$domain[0] OK";
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

test.txt contains this

```
www.google.com  2.2.2.3
www.test.com    2.2.2.3
www.example.com 2.2.2.3
```

after I ran my script the result is this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "www.google.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.google.com OK
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "www.test.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.test.com OK
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.example.com OK
array(0) {
}
 OK
```

What cause the `array(0)` to appear?
There's no new line after www.example.com or other element.
Can I remove it or simply don't get it generated?

Comment: Why not just use `file` function?`foreach(file($file) as $line)` instead of `file_get_contents + explode`

Comment: is that the same result? I'll try it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra linebreak or other whitespace character after the last domain.

Trim the text file contents first:

```
$open = trim(file_get_contents($file));
```

You could also check if the line isn't empty inside the loop.

```
$file="test.txt";
$open = trim(file_get_contents($file));  // Either this..
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $open);
foreach($lines as $line){

    if ($line === '') // Or this
        continue;


    $domain = preg_split('/\s+/', $line,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($domain);
    echo "$domain[0] OK";
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've try trim but it is inside the foreach loop so it donesn't work but now it works well!

Answer (score 0):

Check what contains the last line with:

```
var_dump($line);
```

If it contains empty string, just add some check:

```
if ( empty($line) ) {
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for such an example:

#### Just names

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$open = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('/^\S+/m', $open, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
Array
(
    [0] => www.google.com
    [1] => www.test.com
    [2] => www.example.com
)
```

#### Names and numbers

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$open = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/m', $open, $matches);
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => www.google.com  2.2.2.3
            [1] => www.test.com    2.2.2.3
            [2] => www.example.com 2.2.2.3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => www.google.com
            [1] => www.test.com
            [2] => www.example.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.2.2.3
            [1] => 2.2.2.3
            [2] => 2.2.2.3
        )

)

$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($result);
Array
(
    [www.google.com] => 2.2.2.3
    [www.test.com] => 2.2.2.3
    [www.example.com] => 2.2.2.3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [`SplFileObject`](http://de.php.net/SplFileObject) instead:

```
$path = "test.txt";
$file = new SplFileObject($path);

$file->setFlags(
    SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE   # new line characters at the end of line
    | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY    # skip empty lines, e.g. the one at the end
);

foreach ($file as $line)
{
    $domain = preg_split('/\s+/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    echo "<pre>", var_dump($domain), "$domain[0] OK", "</pre>";
}
```

It not only has support for your issue build in (see the flags) but also parses the file line by line, so for larger files it would not shift it completely into the memory. See as well the [`file`](http://de.php.net/file) function.

Comment: I would also suggest the SplFileObject, little side note: in order to let SKIP_EMPTY do its job you also need READ_AHEAD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806111/how-to-remove-the-extra-line-when-using-php-splfileobject-and-read-csv-flag

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and found that it's working perfectly...
I got this output by same code

```
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "www.google.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.google.com OK

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "www.test.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.test.com OK

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2.2.2.3"
}
www.example.com OK
```

I think there is new line [enter] in your text file please remove it using backspace and it will work fine..

Comment: it's solve after I use trim(file_get_contents($file)). I think there might be space or tab (\n or \t) somewhere else.