# How to remove the extra line when using PHP SplFileObject and READ_CSV flag?

Tags: php

When iterating over a csv file using PHP [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) and the `READ_CSV` flag I get an extra row with a `null` value. Is there a way to remove this line automatically?

```
$file = new SplFileObject(__DIR__.'/technologies.csv', 'r');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

This will produce a row with a `null` value.

```
...
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  NULL
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to also set the [`SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.skip-empty) flag, and for that to work also the [`SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.read-ahead) flag.

The [`SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.skip-empty) flag does what it says on the tin: it skips empty lines. A trailing newline in your file counts as an empty line.

<sup>(Aside: [`SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.read-ahead) is needed so that [`SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php#splfileobject.constants.skip-empty) can do its job. The next line needs to be read, internally, so that PHP can determine if it is empty or not.)</sup>

---

So, your code will look like (wrapped on to multiple lines so you can read it):

```
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV |
                SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY |
                SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
```

Comment: Also I added SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE   flag

Answer (score 2):

I am using PHP 8.0.18 & I had to add one more flag in order to skip the empty lines, ie `SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE`. The final code looks like;

```php
$file->setFlags(
            SplFileObject::READ_CSV |
            SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY |
            SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE |
            SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD
        );
```